# Getting information of a Chinese character in Windows

Tags: windows

In Asian Microsoft Windows like Korean, Japanese, Chinese, IME has a Chinese character converter.

For instance, In Korean Windows, it contains Chinese character dictionary internally.

[image]

how can i access and getting information to this internal dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Accessing Candidate Strings using Active Accessibility Support by IME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971336#atg_tsf_topic2)